# Reading an Image file from External Storage and placing in an ImageView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-external-storage

I've a situation in which I need to populate an image view with an image from the user's external storage directory; I've been decoding a file using a Bitmap Factory and then setting the image view bitmap accordingly, but I keep running into Null Pointer Exceptions.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Pictures/test.jpg";
File imgFile = new File(path);

    if(imgFile.exists()){
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    } else {
        Log.d("Ciaren", "File doesn't exist");
    }
```

I'm running this directly in OnCreate, and the image view should be full screen, I can't for the life of me figure out what is throwing a null object though, as I've stepped through and all seems fine, the null pointer is thrown when the setImageBitmap(); method is called.

Comment: have you set your view with setContnetView();

Comment: If it's thrown when the setImageBitmap() method is called your ImageView is null. Make sure imageView2 is the correct Id. sometime a Project > Clean works.

Comment: your imageview object is null ther i think..

Comment: @RobertHahn Ahhhhhhhh the ID of the image view was wrong, human error at its peak, thanks for pointing that out, would you like to put it as an answer so I could mark it as accepted? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown in imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); and thus imageView is null. As a result your imageView is not found. Make sure the resource id R.id.imageView2 is correct. Sometimes there are problems with eclipse and a Project > Clean can fix that too.